# Understanding `memory_order_acquire` and `memory_order_release` in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm reading through [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) and more specifically

> **memory_order_acquire**: A load operation with this memory order performs
>   the acquire operation on the affected memory location: no reads or
>   writes in the current thread can be reordered before this load. All
>   writes in other threads that release the same atomic variable are
>   visible in the current thread (see Release-Acquire ordering below).
>
> **memory_order_release**: A store operation with this memory order
>   performs the release operation: no reads or writes in the current
>   thread can be reordered after this store. All writes in the current
>   thread are visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic
>   variable (see Release-Acquire ordering below) and writes that carry a
>   dependency into the atomic variable become visible in other threads
>   that consume the same atomic (see Release-Consume ordering below)

These two bits:

from *memory_order_acquire*

> ... no reads or writes in the current thread can be re-ordered before this load...

from *memory_order_release*

> ... no reads or writes in the current thread can be re-ordererd after this store...

What exactly do they mean?

There's also this example

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

std::atomic<std::string*> ptr;
int data;

void producer()
{
    std::string* p  = new std::string("Hello");
    data = 42;
    ptr.store(p, std::memory_order_release);
}

void consumer()
{
    std::string* p2;
    while (!(p2 = ptr.load(std::memory_order_acquire)))
        ;
    assert(*p2 == "Hello"); // never fires
    assert(data == 42); // never fires
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(producer);
    std::thread t2(consumer);
    t1.join(); t2.join();
}
```

But I cannot really figure where the two bits I've quoted apply. I understand what's happening but I don't really see the re-ordering bit because the code is small.

Comment: Keep in mind that cppreference is unofficial documentation, meant to be a more readable summary of the C++ standard written collectively by Wiki contributors.  It's usually pretty good, but is in no way authoritative.  One thing in particular is that they describe the memory model in terms of reordering: this is completely different from the standard itself which uses an abstract happens-before description, and sometimes subtle details are lost or left unclear in the translation.

Comment: @NateEldredge though the C++ standard does not explicitly talk about instruction reordering in the case of various memory orderings, I believe there must be some guarantees.

Take, for example, _implementing a lock_; it'll use `acquire-load` semantics for a successful lock and `release-store` semantics for the unlock. Now, **there must be a guarantee that instructions after the `acquire-load`, in program order, are not reordered before it**; otherwise, we would have a situation where the code's critical section is reordered before the `acquire-load` of the lock, which can cause a data race.

Comment: @TheGhostJoker: The Standard only defines observable behavior, which at the end of the day, is entirely determined by the values returned by the program's loads, and memory ordering tells you which of the values stored elsewhere in the program may or may not be returned by any given load.  Of course, in real life, typical machines can only accomplish that by inhibiting reordering in the way you describe.  But in theory, if there were a way for a given machine to reorder its instructions while still preserving the desired semantics, it would be free to do so.

Comment: @TheGhostJoker: To put it another way, we can say in effect that the implementation must behave **as if** memory accesses that follow an acquire load in program order are not reordered before it.  But what's actually going on under the hood is anybody's guess.

Comment: @TheGhostJoker: But as one slightly less outlandish possibility, in your example of an acquire load, the Standard only promises synchronization when the acquire load observes the value of a release store.  If the compiler could somehow prove that the program never makes a release store to the object in question, then it could disregard the barrier effect of the acquire load, and freely reorder around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acquire and Release are Memory Barriers.
If your program reads data after an acquire barrier you are assured you will be reading data consistent in order with any preceding release by any other thread in respect of the same atomic variable. Atomic variables are guaranteed to have an absolute order (when using `memory_order_acquire` and `memory_order_release` though weaker operations are provided for) to their reads and writes across all threads. These barriers in effect propagate that order to any threads using that atomic variable.
You can use atomics to indicate something has 'finished' or is 'ready' but if the consumer reads other than the atomic variable the consumer can't rely on 'seeing' the right 'versions' of other memory and atomics would have limited value.

The statements about 'moving before' or 'moving after' are instructions to the optimizer that it shouldn't re-order operations to take place out of order. Optimizers are very good at re-ordering instructions and even omitting redundant reads/writes but if they re-organise the code across the memory barriers they may unwittingly violate that order.

Your code relies on the `std::string` object (a) having been constructed in `producer()` before `ptr` is assigned and (b) the constructed version of that string (i.e. the version of the memory it occupies) being the one that `consumer()` reads.
Put simply `consumer()` is going to eagerly read the string as soon as it sees `ptr` assigned so it damn well better see a valid and fully constructed object or bad times will ensue.
In that code 'the act' of assigning `ptr` is how `producer()` 'tells' `consumer` the string is 'ready'. The memory barrier exists to make sure that's what the consumer sees.

Conversely if `ptr` was declared as an ordinary `std::string *` then the compiler could decide to optimize `p` away and assign the allocated address directly to `ptr` and only then construct the object and assign the `int` data. That is likely a disaster for the `consumer` thread which is using that assignment as the indicator that the objects `producer` is preparing are ready.
To be accurate if `ptr` were a pointer the `consumer` may never see the value assigned or on some architectures read a partially assigned value where only some of the bytes have been assigned and it points to a garbage memory location. However those aspects are about it being atomic not the wider memory barriers.

Comment: I think you're answer is the most complete one. Can you have a look at this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59651328/stdmemory-order-and-instruction-order-clarification

Comment: "Atomic variables are guaranteed to have an absolute order to their reads and writes across all threads." Is this really true? I think that guarantee is provided by SC or stronger, not atomics in general.

Comment: @eric Fair comment. `memory_order_acquire` and `memory_order_release' ensure sequential consistency of atomics but weaker operations such as `memory_order_relaxed` are provided for. I've amended the answer accordingly.
This is a very subtle area and I appreciate any corrections that improve clarity.

Comment: @Persixty, how does `memory_order_acquire` and `memory_order_release` ensure sequential consistency?

Comment: @Eric Because they imply memory barriers so other threads that access the same atomic variable will experience sequential consistency in the sense that in the above example the `std::string` object will appear to have happened (in full) before the atomic pointer was set.

Comment: @Persixty, okay, I see what you're trying to say but it's wrong to describe that as sequential consistency. Sequential consistency guarantees that all memory accesses have a total order. This is not true for acquire/release semantics as threads may observe updates in different orders.

Comment: @Persixty, I think what you're trying to describe is the synchronizes-with relation. That is, the write-release synchronizes with the read-acquire and any writes that happen before the write-release become visible side effects in the thread performing the read-acquire.

Comment: @Eric I am but with the minimum baffling terminology being imported.

Answer (score 9):

The work done by a thread is not guaranteed to be visible to other threads.

To make data visible between threads, a synchronization mechanism is needed. A non-relaxed `atomic` or a `mutex` can be used for that. It's called the acquire-release semantics. Writing a mutex "releases" all memory writes before it and reading the same mutex "acquires" those writes.

Here we use `ptr` to "release" work done so far (`data = 42`) to another thread:

```
    data = 42;
    ptr.store(p, std::memory_order_release); // changes ptr from null to not-null
```

And here we *wait* for that, and by doing that we *synchronize* ("acquire") the work done by the producer thread:

```
    while (!ptr.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) // assuming initially ptr is null
        ;
    assert(data == 42);
```

Note two distinct actions:

1. we *wait* between threads (the synchronization step)
2. as a side effect of the *wait*, we get to *transfer* work from the provider to the consumer (the provider *releases* and the consumer *acquires* it)

In the absence of (2), e.g. when using `memory_order_relaxed`, only the `atomic` value itself is synchronized. All other work done before/after isn't, e.g. `data` won't necessarily contain `42` and there may not be a fully constructed `string` instance at the address `p` (as seen by the consumer).

For more details about acquire/release semantics and other details of the C++ memory model I would recommend watching Herb's excellent [*atomic<> weapons talk*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8eCGOqgvH4), it's long but is fun to watch. And for even more details there's a book called *"C++ Concurrency in Action"*.

Comment: With reference to the documentation what does "re-ordering before/after" mean? (namely the two specific quotes in my question).

Comment: ok, that makes a lot of sense.  but raises the question what does `ptr.store(p, std::memory_order_aquire)` mean?  If it's completely meaningless, then why is it an option?

Comment: @UKMonkey which order values can be specified for a `store` are specified in [\[atomics.order\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/atomics.order). `memory_order_acquire` isn't one of them, because it makes no sense. So strictly speaking the code `ptr.store(p, std::memory_order_acquire)` would invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @rustyx thanks :) I think I understand it all a bit better now!

Answer (score 3):

If you used `std::memory_order_relaxed` for the store, the compiler could use the "as-if" rule to move `data = 42;` to after the store, and `consumer` could see a non-null pointer and indeterminate `data`.

If you used `std::memory_order_relaxed` for the load, the compiler could use the "as-if" rule to move the `assert(data == 42);` to before the load loop.

Both of these are allowed because the value of `data` is not related to the value of `ptr`

If instead `ptr` were non-atomic, you'd have a data race and therefore undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. As far as I understand the `memory_order_relaxed` would imply re-ordering of instructions, but it would preserve `atomicity` and `order consistency`. My interpretation of the example in my question is that no instruction before/after the store/load would be re-ordered, what I struggle to understand is how this differs from the `order consistency` guaranteed by the `relaxed` model. Is there a better example (code) that can show this?

Comment: @user8469759 If you do a bunch of `memory_order_relaxed` stores to a single variable on one thread, other threads can't see those out of order (e.g. incrementing a counter remains monotonic), but there are no constraints on operations affecting other variables.

Comment: @user8469759 I think that the `assert(*p2 == "Hello");` in the example is a red herring. The only way that can appear to fire is in the non-atomic, undefined behaviour case.

Comment: @user8469759 Where did you get from that the relaxed memory order provides _order consistency_? AFAIK, relaxed operations only guarantee atomicity, and does not provide any ordering guarantees.

Comment: From the page I linked, I quote : *Atomic operations tagged memory_order_relaxed are not synchronization operations; they do not impose an order among concurrent memory accesses. They only guarantee atomicity and modification order consistency. * Unless I missunderstood

Comment: @user8469759 that's what you are misunderstanding. "modification order consistency" is only referring to modifications to *that* variable

Comment: I still don't get the difference with the `relase` and `acquire`, do the `read/write` mentioned apply to other variables as well?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this talk: it's long, but he really gives good explanations of all the details of atomics and the memory model: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2

Comment: @user8469759 `release` is meaningless for loads, and `acquire` is meaningless for stores. They are distinct because an exchange can desire neither, one, the other or both.

Comment: Can I kindly ask what sort of modification do I need to make to snippet I've posted in order to see the effects of these modes? There's an example in the page I linked with the `consume` mode where the `assert(data == 42)` should fire, in my case nothing happens. Is there maybe some slightly more elaborate example I can run?

Comment: There isn't a sensible change that means the assert *should* fire. Putting `std::memory_order_relaxed` in instead means that the assert *can* fire and the implementation is still conforming to the standard

Comment: A conforming implementation can choose to ignore what you pass and treat everything the same as `std::memory_order_seq_cst`

Comment: To be honest I need an extended answer... I'm gonna watch the video suggested by @mvd and see how it goes.

Comment: Silly question, still watching the video, is essentially this `acquire/release` semantic what `lock/unlock` on a mutex does? So in the example one thread is `locking/acquiring` and the other is `unlocking/releasing` is it right?

Comment: Is anyone willing to have a chat with me where this can be clarified?

Comment: @mvd That link is broken for me but I think you can use this instead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8eCGOqgvH4