# C++ proper atomic memory ordering on a "thread barrier" synchronization pattern

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, stdatomic, spinlock

I need to properly synchronize access to some shared resource between a predefined number of worker threads (statically known via application config) and a predefined number of control-plane threads. The control-plane threads receive requests from the outside, and based on that potentially modify the shared resource. Worker threads simply run an infinite loop inside of which the shared resource is read only. To do this in a thread-safe way, and given the actual application use-case (network packet processing, multi data-plane threads and multi control-plane threads), it was decided to implement a "thread barrier" kind of pattern. Here's a snippet for how it's done, assuming the application is configured to spawn 2 worker threads and 2 control-plane threads:

```
std::atomic_bool barrier{};
std::atomic_uint32_t workers_at_barrier{};

// called by control-plane threads only!
void barrier_lock()
{
    // optimized spinlock implementation: rigtorp.se/spinlock/
    while (true)
    {
        if (!barrier.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acquire))
            break;

        while (barrier.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
            __builtin_ia32_pause();
    }
    assert(barrier);

    // wait for ALL worker (data-plane) threads to arrive at the barrier!
    while (workers_at_barrier.load() != 2);
    assert(workers_at_barrier.load() == 2);
}

// called by control-plane threads only!
void barrier_unlock()
{
    assert(barrier && workers_at_barrier.load() == 2);
    barrier.store(false, std::memory_order_release);

    // wait for ALL workers to get out of the barrier!
    while (workers_at_barrier.load() != 0);
}

struct barrier_lock_guard
{
    barrier_lock_guard()
    {
        barrier_lock();
    }

    ~barrier_lock_guard()
    {
        barrier_unlock();
    }
};

// control-plane threads receive some requests and handles them here
void handle_stuff()
{
    // ... stuff

    {
        barrier_lock_guard blg;

        // barrier should be set and all workers (2 in this case) should be waiting at the barrier for its release
        assert(barrier && workers_at_barrier.load() == 2);

        // ... writes to shared resource
    }

    // ... stuff
}

// called by worker threads only!
void wait_at_barrier()
{
    // immediately return if barrier is not set
    if (!barrier.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
        return;
    
    ++workers_at_barrier;

    // block at the barrier until it gets released
    while (barrier.load(std::memory_order_acquire));

    --workers_at_barrier;
}

// function run by the worker threads
void workers_stuff()
{
    while (true)
    {
        wait_at_barrier();

        // ... reads from shared resource
    }
}
```

The problem is that the assert `assert(barrier && workers_at_barrier.load() == 2);` in `handle_stuff()` is getting hit. This occurs very very rarely, so there must be something wrong, and I'm trying to understand exactly what and where. Pretty sure though it has something to do with an incorrect use of `std::memory_order`. Any C++ atomics pro out there that can point me to the exact issue and what the proper fix would be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue you're having (atomics using memory orders other than sequentially consistent are hard), wouldn't a reader-writer lock also work well in this scenario?

Comment: Assume that changing the synchronization pattern is not an option. I'm just trying to understand what would be the most correct way to fix this by sticking to the "thread barrier" pattern.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to block all worker threads at the 'barrier' when a writer thread needs to modify the shared resource, and allow the worker threads to free-run when the barrier is false.  The premise being that if all readers are blocked, it must be safe to write.  Is this the correct interpretation of what you are doing?  (trying to understand the exact intent of the code...)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59626494/understanding-memory-order-acquire-and-memory-order-release-in-c11#59627953  might be helpful.  I think you somehow need to "protect" the ++workers_at_barrier with an acquire/release sequence.  The first answer in the link may help.

Comment: That being said, it seems like this is a scheme to avoid mutexes and condition variables that might do more blocking and spinning that just using a more conventional pattern that releases the readers with a condition variable.  I think this version of "lock free" might be slower than using mutexes/condition variables.

Comment: @ttemple your understanding is correct. Using a more conventional pattern though won't change as the worker threads are pinned to dedicated CPU isolated cores, isolated as of "isolcpus" kernel boot parameter.

Comment: I have a feeling that it might just be the asserts.  I think the code may be correct, but the asserts are looking at two atomics that are not synchronized.  Everywhere else the atomics stand alone in their functionality, and I suspect that the code may be functioning correctly, and the asserts are getting fooled because of the lack of enforced synchronization between 'barrier' and 'workers_at_barrier'.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a memory ordering issue, just a plain race.  I can reproduce it even after upgrading all the memory orderings to sequential consistency.  [Here is my version on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GG7jvsqsn) though I can only reproduce the failure locally (godbolt only runs on one core).

The comment `wait for ALL workers to get out of the barrier!` in `barrier_unlock` seems to point to the problem.  This loop doesn't force *another* control thread to wait; that other thread could take the barrier right away.

Alternatively, observing the value `workers_at_barrier == 2` in `barrier_lock()` does not prove that both threads are now waiting at the barrier; they may have already passed it while it was previously down, but not yet gotten around to decrementing the atomic counter.

So imagine the following sequence of events.  We have control threads C1,C2, and worker threads W1,W2.  C1 has taken the barrier and is just entering `barrier_unlock()`.  C2 is just entering `barrier_lock()`.  W1 and W2 are both spinning in the `while(barrier.load())` in `wait_at_barrier()`, and `workers_at_barrier` has the value `2`.

1. C1: `barrier.store(false)`
2. W1: `barrier.load()`: `false`, spin loop exits
3. C2: `barrier.exchange(true)`: returns `false`.  Break out of loop.  Now `barrier == true`.
4. C2: `assert(barrier)` (passes)
5. C2: `workers_at_barrier.load()`: 2.  The `while` loop exits immediately.
6. C2: `assert(workers_at_barrier.load() == 2)` (passes)
7. C2 returns from `barrier_lock()`
8. W1: `--workers_at_barrier`: 1
9. C2 in `handle_stuff()`: Now `barrier == true` and `workers_at_barrier == 1`.  The assertion fails.

I'm not sure of the best fix offhand.  Perhaps `barrier` should have a third "draining" state, in which the control thread still owns the barrier but the workers can leave it.  Only after they have done so does the control thread fully release the barrier.

Comment: Yep, I see the bug now. IMHO ensuring that `workers_at_barrier == 0` immediately before setting `barrier` might be the fix here. What do you think? Btw thank you so much for the thorough explanation, it really helped a lot.

Comment: @pa5h1nh0: That won't help, because your code already does that.  Assuming `handle_stuff` is in an infinite loop as in my implementation, `barrier_lock()` gets called immediately after `barrier_unlock()`, which does check that `workers_at_barrier == 0` before returning (the while loop at its end).  You can include that in the sequence I gave if you add a few more of the preceding steps.

Comment: @pa5h1nh0: Trying to think about "immediately before" in multithreading is usually a mistake.  No matter how close together two operations are in a single thread, any other thread may do an arbitrary of stuff in between, unless your program logic prevents it.

Comment: @pa5h1nh0: Another possible fix is to integrate `barrier` and `workers_at_barrier` into a single variable that all threads can modify atomically.  Then you won't have the race where the two have to be modified separately and can get out of sync.  But then the necessary operations on that variable will be a bit more complex, and probably have to be done with a `compare_exchange` loop instead of simple boolean or arithmetic operations.

Comment: Allow me to comment on "because your code already does that". Currently it's doing that in `barrier_unlock()` AFTER releasing `barrier` (I'd use `seq_cst` on both atomics if required to make sure of this "after"), therefore only the thread owning the lock and releasing it ensures of that, which is exactly the problem. Instead, making sure that `workers_at_barrier == 0` is actually required imho for all control plane threads immediately BEFORE they attempt to set the `barrier` in `barrier_lock()`. Hopefully using `seq_cst` on both atomics would keep all this sequentially ordered.

Comment: So I'd move the `wait for ALL workers to get out of the barrier!` loop in `barrier_lock()` instead, inside of the `while (true)` that tries to set `barrier` and immediately before actually setting it, all of them with the default `seq_cst` memory order.

Comment: @pa5h1nh0: Still doesn't help.  It's irrelevant what functions or loops they are in, only the sequence of operations matters.  All of your proposed changes still have the C2 thread load the value of `workers_at_barrier` and then test-and-set `barrier` as two operations in that order, and therefore it is possible for all the stuff with C1, W1, W2 to happen in between.  Once again, there is no way to get one operation to happen "immediately before" the other in such a way that other threads cannot intervene, unless they are actually a single atomic operation, or protected by a lock, etc.

Comment: And keep in mind that `seq_cst` only ensures that loads and stores happen in a *well-defined* order which interleaves the accesses done by the individual threads, but says nothing about how that interleaving is done.  You can assume that all the operations will be "shuffled" together in some fashion, but you still have to account for all the possible ways in which that shuffling can occur.  Memory ordering will not help with the latter.