# Can atomic RMW seq_cst followed and preceded by an atomic load acquire be reordered on x86?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I have a pattern like the following:

```
std::atomic_uint32_t x{};
std::atomic_bool y{};

void wait_at_y()
{
    if (!y.load(std::memory_order_acquire))     // 1
        return;

    x++;  // uses seq_cst by default            // 2

    // spin until 'y' is set 'false'
    while (y.load(std::memory_order_acquire));  // 3

    x--;  // uses seq_cst by default            // 4
}

// function run by N threads
void foo()
{
    while (running)
    {
        wait_at_y();

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Does `wait_at_y()` written this way guarantee on x86 that `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` will get executed exactly in this order, i.e. without reordering any of them? If not, what is required to prevent any reordering? [Atomic memory fences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) maybe, if yes where?

Comment: "Without reordering" isn't usually a helpful way to think about memory barriers.  What actual goals do you want to achieve?  What observable behavior should the code exhibit?  What invariants must be preserved?  It's also not possible to say much about this code without the context of how `y` will be written, and how that needs to interact with whatever else the writing thread will do.

Comment: But to answer the question literally, reordering is possible with this code. First note that the RMWs at #2 and #4 are each two operations, a read and a write, for purposes of memory ordering.  The atomicity ensures that no other read or write of `x` can take place in between them, but the same is not true for reads and writes of other variables such as `y`.  And so nothing prevents load #3 from becoming visible before the write of #2.  Without seeing more context, it's hard to tell whether that would be a problem.

Comment: If you insist that all operations must be observed in this sequence by all observers, your only recourse is to make *all* the accesses `seq_cst`, not only the ones shown here in `wait_for_y` but also those in whatever other threads are accessing those variables and need to observe the sequencing.

Comment: The reordering mentioned above will *probably* not happen on x86 because atomic RMWs have a full barrier.  But that's not a guarantee of the language, and compiler optimizations could conceivably break it.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for your input. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72897743/3222975) is a sample of how `y` is written and `x` is read. Overall I think you might be correct though, everything with `seq_cst`.

Answer (score 0):

Both x, y are atomic variables, and all operation is doing in sequential consistency.

**Yes**, 1, 2, 3, 4 will get executed exactly in this order.
You don’t need to insert atomic memory fence anywhere.

But it does not guarantee that your program is correct. You can meet data races elsewhere.